# Troubleshooting session states in switch statement

Tags: php, session, switch-statement

I am using sessions to save the state. The states are being saved, as I have checked this. However only when the session is set to state 4 (sort email) are the other functions sorting the database by email upon completion. If i select any other sort (states 1-3), then the session is saved yet once any other functions (delete/update etc) are called the data reverts back to sorting by ID. Why is this only working when data is sorted by email (state 4) and not when it is sorted by the other 3 states? I can't seem to find this bug.

```
<?php

// include database configuration
include "dbheader.php";

// model with database and business logic code
include "crud.model.php";

// make my TPL array at the top, because it might be populated during 
// the switch actions
$TPL = array(); 

$TPL[‘displayTable’] = true;
$TPL[‘updateTable’] = false;
$TPL["fetchedrecord"] = [];

session_start();

switch ($_REQUEST["act"]) { 

  case "updatestart":
          $recordid = $_REQUEST["id"];
          $TPL["fetchedrecord"] = fetchRecord($conn, $recordid);
          $TPL[‘displayTable’] = false;
          $TPL[‘updateTable’] = true;

      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 1){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 2){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 3){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 4){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataEmail($conn);
      }
      else{
        $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
      }
  break;

  // updating a record from the database 
  case "update":

      updateRecord($conn,
              $_REQUEST["id"],
              $_REQUEST["fnameUP"],
              $_REQUEST["lnameUP"],
              $_REQUEST["phoneUP"],
              $_REQUEST["emailUP"],
              $_REQUEST["locationUP"],
              $_REQUEST["mcUP"],
              $_REQUEST["posUP"],
              $_REQUEST["deptUP"]);
            $TPL[‘displayTable’] = true;
            $TPL[‘updateTable’] = false;

      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 1){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 2){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 3){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 4){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataEmail($conn);
      }
      else{
        $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
      }

    break;

  // deleting a record from the database 
  case "delete":

    $recordid = $_REQUEST["id"];
      deleteRecord($conn, $recordid);
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 1){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 2){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 3){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 4){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataEmail($conn);
      }
      else{
        $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
      }

    break;


  // sorting records by last nae 
  case "sortname":
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
        $_SESSION["sess"] = 1;
    break;

  case "sortemail":
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataEmail($conn); 
        $_SESSION["sess"] = 4;
    break;

  case "sortposition":
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn);  
        $_SESSION["sess"] = 2;
    break;

  case "sortdepartment":
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
        $_SESSION["sess"] = 3;
    break;

  // insert a new record into the database  
  case "insert":

      insertRecord($conn,
              $_REQUEST["fname"],
              $_REQUEST["lname"],
                  $_REQUEST["phone"],
                  $_REQUEST["email"],
              $_REQUEST["location"],
              $_REQUEST["mc"],
              $_REQUEST["pos"],
              $_REQUEST["dept"]);
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 1){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 2){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn); 
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 3){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
      }
      if($_SESSION["sess"] == 4){
        $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataEmail($conn);
      }
      else{
        $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
      }
    break;

  default:  
     $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
}

// put code here for things that need to happen every time the page loads



// view with our user interface
include "crud.view.php";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a series of `if` statements that are not tied to each other, but you are still attempting to use an `else` at the end. Each `if` in these blocks needs to be an `elseif`:

```
if ($_SESSION["sess"] == 1) {
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
} elseif($_SESSION["sess"] == 2) {
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn); 
} elseif($_SESSION["sess"] == 3) {
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
} elseif($_SESSION["sess"] == 4) {
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataEmail($conn);
} else{
    $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
}
```

The way you have it structured currently, if it is matching anything other than the last condition, it will ALSO match the else, which does not appear to be your intention.

Another option would be a switch statement:

```
switch ($tpl['phonebook']) {
    case 1:  sortDataLName($conn);      break;
    case 2:  sortDataPosition($conn);   break;
    case 3:  sortDataDepartment($conn); break;
    case 4:  sortDataEmail($conn);      break;
    default: getAllData($conn);         break;
}
```